# Find, unzip and grep the content of multiple files in one step/command

Tags: shell, logging, command-line, zip

First I made a question here: [Unzip a file and then display it in the console in one step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56627719/unzip-a-file-and-then-display-it-in-the-console-in-one-step)
It works and helped me a lot. (please read)

Now I have a second issue. I do not have a single `zipped log file` but I have a lot of them in defferent folders, which I need to find first. The files have the same names. For example:

```
/somedir/server1/log.gz
/somedir/server2/log.gz
/somedir/server3/log.gz
```

and so on...

What I need is a way to:

1. find all the files like: `find /somedir/server* -type f -name log.gz`
2. unzip the files like: `gunzip -c log.gz`
3. use `grep` on the content of the files

Important! The whole should be done in one step.
I cannot first store the extracted files in the filesystem because it is a readonly filesystem. I need somehow to connect, with pipes, the output from one command to the input of the next.

Before, the log files were in text format (.txt), therefore I had not to unzip them first. In this case it was easy:
ex.
`find /somedir/server* -type f -name log.txt | xargs grep "term"`

Now I have to deal with zipped files. That means, after I find the files, I need first somehow do unzip them and then send the contents to `grep`.
With one file I do:
`gunzip -p /somedir/server1/log.gz | grep term`
But for multiple files I don't know how to do it. For example how to pass the output of `find` to `gunzip` and the to `grep`?!

Also if there is another way / "best practise" how to do that, it is welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` lets you invoke a command on the files it finds:

```
find /somedir/server* -type f -name log.gz -exec gunzip -c '{}' + | grep ...
```

From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

> `-exec command {} +`
>
> This variant of the -exec action runs the specified command on
>   the selected files, but the command line is built by appending
>   each selected file name at the end; the total number of
>   invocations of the command will be much less than the number
>   of matched files.  The command line is built in much the same
>   way that xargs builds its command lines.  Only one instance of
>   `{}` is allowed within the command, and (when find is being
>   invoked from a shell) it should be quoted (for example, `'{}'`)
>   to protect it from interpretation by shells.  The command is
>   executed in the starting directory.  If any invocation with
>   the `+` form returns a non-zero value as exit status, then
>   find returns a non-zero exit status.  If find encounters an
>   error, this can sometimes cause an immediate exit, so some
>   pending commands may not be run at all.  This variant of -exec
>   always returns true.

Comment: It works exactly as I need. I am not sure how it does what it does, I mean I am not sure what {} and + do in this case, but I need to search more about it. Thank you!